# How to make a column in SQL made with the values of several other columns?

Tags: mysql, sql

How do I make a column in a database table based on the values of other columns? For example: I want to make a column named "full_name" and I want the row values for it to be from "first_name" and "last_name". For the first row:  first_name= Bob and last_name=Jones. How do I make it so that full_name gets Bob Jones as its value? (I prefer it done in one command if possible).

Comment: `one_column + '  ' + another_column as third_column`

Comment: Computed column - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188300.aspx

Comment: In MySQL you can use the `CONCAT` function: `CONCAT(first_name, ' ', last_name)`.  By the way, you never told us which flavor of SQL you are using.

Comment: Do you want to create the column permanently or just for the query ?

Comment: Which dbms? As you can see in the above comments, many products are not ANSI SQL compliant when it comes to concatenation.

Comment: Permanently in the table

Comment: But why? Computed values are redundant, and you need to prevent data inconsistency. (triggers) Create a view instead!

Comment: Ok, so do it for just the query? Btw, its MySQL

Answer (score 0):

First create the new column:

```
ALTER TABLE myTable
ADD 'Full Name' varchar;
```

Second move the existing first and last name into the new column:

```
UPDATE TABLE myTable
```

//this is where it differs from which sql you are using
Either for mysql:

```
SET 'Full Name' = CONCAT_WS(' ',firstname,lastname);
```

OR for transact sql:

```
SET 'Full Name' = (firstname + ' ' + lastname);
```

Or for oracle:

```
SET 'Full Name' = (firstname || ' ' || lastname);
```

(I don't think there are any other ways of putting this)

Then lastly drop the columns firstname and lastname so you can keep using full name (you don't have to drop the columns you can edit your insert query so it also automatically inserts full name but that would be redundant data)

```
ALTER TABLE myTable
DROP COLUMN firstname, lastname;
```

Answer (score 0):

No need to store same data twice, create a view instead:

```
create view viewname as
  select first_name || last_name as full_name, ...
  from tablename
```

`||` is ANSI SQL concatenation. Some products use `+` or `concat()` instead.

With this solution you will not get any data inconsistency. (When somebody updates just one of the name columns...)